# FunkLoad monitor doesn't show any graphs in report

Tags: funkload

I did set up everything according to tutorial here http://funkload.nuxeo.org/monitoring.html , started monitor server, made bench test, builded report. But in report there are no added graphs from monitoring... Any idea? I am using credential server as well, but that was and is working correctly... its just that after i added monitor things, nothing seems to change...

monitor.conf

```
[server]
host = localhost
port = 8008
interval = .5
interface = eth0
[client]
host = localhost
port = 8008
```

my_test.conf:

```
[main]
title= some title
description= some descr
url=http://localhost:8000
... some other not important lines here

[monitor]
hosts=localhost

[localhost]
port=8008
description=The benching machine
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
sudo easy_install -f http://funkload.nuxeo.org/snapshots/ -U funkload
```

instead of just

```
pip install funkload
```

Looks like pip does have some old bad version of funkload